# Detect when rotation has completed and move to new Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement moving to another scene when a wheel stops rotating. The code I have is shown below. I cannot figure out how to detect when the velocity has reached 0.0?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameplayScene: SKScene {

    var player: Player?;

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        player = self.childNode(withName: "spinner") as! Player?;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if atPoint(location).name == "play_button" {
               spin()
            }
        }
    }

    func spin () {
        let random = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 20, highestValue: 90)
        let r = random.nextInt()
        player?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(self.frame.width))
        player?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        player?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        player?.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = CGFloat(r)
        player?.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1.0
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     }
}
```

So from here, I would like to execute the following when the wheel has stopped spinning:

```
let play_scene = Questions(fileNamed: "QuestionsScene")
play_scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(play_scene!, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 1))
```

I have now edited the class and it looks as follows:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameplayScene: SKScene, SKSceneDelegate {


var player: Player?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.delegate = self
    player = self.childNode(withName: "spinner") as! Player?;

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if atPoint(location).name == "play_button" {
            spin()
        }
    }
}
    func spin () {
        let random = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 20, highestValue: 90)
    let r = random.nextInt()
    player?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(self.frame.width))
    player?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    player?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    player?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    player?.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    player?.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = CGFloat(r)
    player?.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1.0

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}
    override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        if ((player?.physicsBody?.angularVelocity)! <= CGFloat(0.01)) 
        {
            print("Got it")
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is I still receive an error on the if statement within didSimulatePhysics function. The error I receive is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wheel's `SKPhysicsBody` has a built-in property, `angularVelocity`, that tells you how fast it's spinning. You're already using it when you set it to `r` to start the wheel spinning.

To watch `angularVelocity` you can use `didSimulatePhysics()`. It gets called once every frame, right after the physics calculations are done. That will look something like this:

```
func didSimulatePhysics() {
    if wheelIsSpinning && angularVelocity != nil && angularVelocity! <= CGFloat(0.001) {
        wheelIsSpinning = false
        // wheel has stopped
        // add your code here
    }
}
```

Due to the vagaries of physics modeling, the angularVelocity might never be exactly zero. So instead we watch for it to be less than some arbitrary threshold, in this case 0.001.

You don't want it to execute every frame when the wheel isn't moving, so I added a property `wheelIsSpinning` to keep track. You'll need to add it as an instance property to `GameplayScene`, and set it to true in `spin()`.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have subsequently found out that even though the wheel looks to have stopped when I print the velocity to console it looks like it's still spinning ever so slowly. It never actually stops

Comment: @Nick Just check for `.angularVelocity <= 0.001` or some other arbitrarily low value.

Comment: Thanks Robert. This is where I receive the error: "binary operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type CGFloat".

Comment: .angularVelocity is a CGFloat so you'll need to compare it to another CGFloat: `.angularVelocity <= CGFloat(0.001)` should do it.

Comment: Hi Robert, appreciate your assistance. I have made the changes but now I receive an error. I suspect it has to do with delegation. Can you explain in a little more detail the delegation in your original response? I have added SKSceneDelegate to the class definition but when I add the "self.delegate = self" statement it is saying that it is expecting a declaration?

Comment: @Robert Setting a scene as its own delegate doesn't make sense. All methods found in `SKSceneDelegate` protocol including `didSimulatePhysics()` are called automatically on a `SKScene` and its subclasses. Setting some other class to implement this protocol would make more sense...

Comment: @Nick Aside from the fact that you don't need that line, if you still want something like that, then put `self.delegate = self` inside of an `init()` or other appropriate methods. You can't use self inside of a body of a class.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thanks for your response. I have also tried removing the SKSceneDelegate reference but still receive an error in the didSimulatePhysics functions. Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: @Nick Remove `SKSceneDelegate` conformance from scene's definition (your scene should look like this `class GameplayScene: SKScene{ }`. Remove `self.delegate = self` from your code. When you do that, tell me what is the error. Everything else Robert said, should work. Conformance to `SKSceneDelegate` is needless. That was my point.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thanks very much. I got it working. My mistake was not to check for velocity is 'nil' as may be the case prior to pressing the spin button. Once I added in a check for 'nil' it worked fine. Thanks again for your help

Comment: SKPhysicsBody has an `isResting` flag to let you know it is no longer moving

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah, but iirc that property will return : "resting,resting,resting,moving" multiple times in a single second, so it is pretty much unusable.

Comment: so would checking at 0

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well, yeah, comparing a `CGFloat` with 0 is very unreliable. I haven't even noticed that part ...

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I tried yesterday using the isResting property, it would work at the beginning before the spin, but after the spin it would never fire again. Reason is because as it would slow down the angularVelocity would go to below 0 thus never be "rested"

Comment: If it goes below zero, then that would mean it would be going backwards, maybe friction and restitution needs tweaking

Comment: @Whirlwind You're right, no need for a delegate at all. My mistake. Answer corrected to reflect.